# NodeJs With Mysql createPool and nodejs mysql wrapper module

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i am using nodejs with mysql createPool and node-mysql-wrapper.

Link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql-wrapper

There is no option in the documentation to implement with module with myslq create pool. I tried it, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit: 100,   
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'test'
        });

var db = wrapper.wrap(connection);      

db.ready(function(){
    db.table("users").findById(8,function(user){
        console.log(user);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `wrapper.wrap()` accepts a `connection` object not a `connectionPool`. You need to call `connection.getConnection(function(err, conn) { wrapper.wrap(conn); })`. See the example here https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Answer (score 0):

As @Tajen Shrestha said. You need bind the wrapper with connection object. For e.g.:

```
var conObj = connection.getConnection.bind(connection);

var db = wrapper.wrap(conObj);      

db.ready(function(){
    db.table("users").findById(8,function(user){
        console.log(user);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined